# Select other items at same level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider following html

```
<ul id="headmenu">
    <li id="headmenuitem1"></li>
    <li id="headmenuitem2"></li>
    <li id="headmenuitem3"></li>
    <li id="headmenuitem4"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to select all other elements when on one item.
For example I am hovering on `headmenuitem1`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#headmenuitem1").hover(function () { //When item is hovered...
        $(this).... //(select all the other items)
     })
 });
```

When doing `this` I need to select all the other items, so in the example, it must select the items `headmenuitem2, headmenuitem3 and headmenuitem4`

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: `$(this).siblings()`

Comment: Did you not read the documentation?

Comment: @Ozkan no it doesn't. Because it shows no research effort, you could have googled this in 5 seconds.

Comment: I don't think siblings does that but in any case use `not` to exclude elements $(this).siblings().not(this)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) `The original element is not included among the siblings`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. all on level except `this`:

   ```
   $(this).siblings();
   ```
2. all on level including `this`, use `.not(this)` to exclude `this`:

   ```
   $(this).parent().children();
   ```
3. immediate previous on the same level:

   ```
   $(this).prev();
   ```
4. immediate next on the same level:

   ```
   $(this).next();
   ```
5. all previous on the same level:

   ```
   $(this).prevAll();
   ```
6. all next on the same level:

   ```
   $(this).nextAll();
   ```

Hope you can understand the syntax by the names themselves...

Comment: `next` and `prev` only get a single adjacent sibling, and `parent().children()` will include the original `this`.

Comment: yeah i have mentioned that in the comment next to the syntax..

Comment: Well *"next on same level"* could mean all the next elements on the same level. Why not mention `prevAll` and `nextAll` instead?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#headmenuitem1").hover(function () { //When item is hovered...
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings(); //(select all the other items)
 })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#headmenu1").hover(function () { //When item is hovered...
        $(this).siblings()...;
     })
 });
```

Do you want this to apply to all li's?  If so you can generalize your selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#headmenu li").hover(function () { //When item is hovered...
        $(this).siblings()...;
     })
 });
```

Comment: Based on comments, it looks like he wants all siblings but **not** the hovered item.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I ninja-edited the andSelf call out

Answer (score 2):

```
var headmenuitem1 = document.getElementById("headmenuitem1");
headmenuitem1.addEventListener("mouseover", hover);
headmenuitem1.addEventListener("mouseout", hover);

function hover() { 
    var nodes = [].slice.call(this.parentNode.children);
    // remove current node
    nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(this), 1);
    console.log(nodes);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/AHBjz/9/)

Comment: He wants all the nodes excluding the `headmenuitem1`. Siblings, basically.

Comment: That'll include text nodes (not just elements), and it doesn't filter out the one that was clicked. I'd +1 it when it meets all the requirements.

Comment: @amnotiam the requirements are vague. including text nodes is feature

Comment: A text node isn't an element. [Node.ELEMENT_NODE == 1 / Node.TEXT_NODE == 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType)

Comment: @amnotiam true he did say he wanted elements

Comment: +1 Because I assume `.children` edit is coming to replace `.childNodes`. ;) ...and there it is!